# How do I fix this expression at the end of my if else statement?

Tags: linux, bash

I need my expression to be able to solve for the next interval divisible by 15 based on input.

Not a very good coder (yet). Tried a lot of (( and [[ and variants of the sort, but I feel the way the code is written is wrong.

```
printf "Enter a number: "
read DVSBL

let ISDIV=$DVSBL

    if [ $(( $ISDIV % 15 )) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $DVSBL is divisible by 15.

    elif [[ $(( $ISDIV % 5 )) -eq 0 && $(( $ISDIV % 15 )) -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo $DVSBL is divisible by 5 and not by 15.

    elif [[ $(( $ISDIV % 3 )) -eq 0 && $(( $ISDIV % 15 )) -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo $DVSBL is divisible by 3 and not by 15.

#from and below is where i am having the most trouble

    else let NXTCLS=$NXTCLS
    $NXTCLS='(( $ISDIV / 15 ) + 1) * 15
        echo The next closest number to $DVSBL that is divisible by 15 is $NXTCLS
    fi
```

everything works in the if statements, but in trying to solve what is wrong with the last couple of lines, i butchered my initial idea and strayed very far from solving this problem.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: BTW, why do you have two separate variables `ISDIV` and `DVSBL` at all? (As an aside, all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself; lowercase names are reserved for application use, and thus are what you should use in your own code).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My mentor made that change really quickly yesterday (I'm an intern). I ran with it, but I will definitely keep that in mind cause I really don't know what I'm doing yet

Comment: ...so, to give you something you can share with your mentor about the "lowercase names are reserved [...] for application use" assertion, see the relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable with a name that overlaps an environment variable will overwrite the latter.

Comment: ...and re: the assertion that `let` is obsolete, http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 1):

Written in modern bash, this might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- this uses bash-only syntax, so shebang must not be #!/bin/sh
#                    or script must be run as ''bash scriptname'', not ''sh scriptname''

read -p "Enter a number: " isdiv

if (( (isdiv % 15) == 0 )); then
    echo "$dvsbl is divisible by 15."
elif (( (isdiv % 5) == 0 && (isdiv % 15) != 0 )); then
    echo "$isdiv is divisible by 5 and not by 15."
elif (( (isdiv % 3) == 0 && (isdiv % 15) != 0 )); then
    echo "$isdiv is divisible by 3 and not by 15."
else
    nxtcls=$(( ( (isdiv / 15) + 1) * 15 ))
    echo "The next closest number to $isdiv that is divisible by 15 is $nxtcls"
fi
```

`let` is ancient syntax from the 1970s, and should never be used in new code. `$(( ))` is the POSIX-specified way to run an arithmetic operation and substitute its result. `(( ))` is a bash-only (thus, for scripts with `#!/bin/bash` shebangs, or otherwise scripts explicitly run by shells with the same extension such as ksh or zsh)

Comment: You have %3 clause messed up, also re-checking for 15 divisibility is redundant as it's eliminated by the first `if`

Comment: True 'nuff on both counts. I'm correcting only the former in the interests of sticking to addressing language issues and not logic bugs.

Comment: Ahh thank you! I was close in a former rendition of the last lines (I definitely had the $ in the wrong place and was missing a set of parenthesis.)